# Robospice sends Retrofit the same request 3 times

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I'm using Robospice with Retrofit module just like in sample.
I'm sending a POST request with body data.

When request returns 200, it's ok.

But when it returns for example error 403, I see it is executing 3 times!
onRequestFailure callback receives the control only after the last request execution.

And log tells that loadDataFromNetwork() method from RetrofitSpiceRequest's descendant class is called 3 times too.

How can I avoid this strange behavior?

Comment: Please show us some code, it will help us figure out the problem, after all, we're not wizards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "retry policy".

> **How can I setup a retry policy for failed requests ?**
>
> Use spiceRequest.setRetryPolicy(). By default, requests have a
>   [DefaultRetryPolicy](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/robospice-core-parent/robospice/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/retry/DefaultRetryPolicy.java). It will be activated when a network request fails.

[Source](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Advanced-RoboSpice-Usages-and-FAQ)